How to upgrade nuget package
I'm trying to update nuget Community.Toolkit.Maui from 6.1.0 to 8.0.0.
I have a dependency restriction for Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility and Microsoft.Maui.Controls set to >= 8.0.14
When i am trying to upgrade Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility to this version it is lowering the Microsoft.Maui.Controls version to 8.0.7 maing it impossible to upgrade the Toolkit.
Am i the only one on the planet who face that situation?

Can you add the package references from your csproj file or specify what versions you have installed or want to install specifically?

i see. you want me just to reference latest nuget from  csproj and then upgrade toolkit. I will try and update you.tnx

I can reproduce the issue and if you want to use Community.Toolkit.Maui 8.0.0, you can follow the workaround below:
You can try to manually edit the csproj file:
Comment out or Remove these two linse in the csproj file.
<PackageReference Include=“Microsoft.Maui.Controls” Version=“$(MauiVersion)” />
<PackageReference Include=“Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility” Version=“$(MauiVersion)” />

And then add these below and save(CTRL+S) to restore to the desired versions.
<PackageReference Include=“Microsoft.Maui.Controls” Version=“8.0.14” />
<PackageReference Include=“Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility” Version=“8.0.14” />

Update:
The issue is being fixed. The default version of Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility and Microsoft.Maui.Controls is 8.0.21 when creating a new .NET 8 project. You can upgrade them to the latest version: 8.0.40 at the same time.
